# Nested Aggregation for AND Query Not Working

Tags: elasticsearch

Please can someone help with the below Question.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nested-aggregation-with-and-always-return-0-match/315722?u=chattes

Answer (score 0):

I have used following aggregations

[1. Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

[2. Bucket selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

[3. Nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html)

First I have grouped by user id using terms aggregation. Then further grouped by  skill Id. Using bucket selector I have filtered users which have documents under two skills.

**Query**

```
GET index5/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "skills": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "skills"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filter_skill": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "skills.id",
                "size": 10,
                "include": [
                  553,
                  426
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "bucket_count": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "skill_count": "skills>filter_skill._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.skill_count ==2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "users" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "skills" : {
            "doc_count" : 3,
            "filter_skill" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "426",
                  "doc_count" : 1
                },
                {
                  "key" : "553",
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "skills" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "filter_skill" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "426",
                  "doc_count" : 1
                },
                {
                  "key" : "553",
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: It kind of works , but here is a better explanation of the problem I am having , can someone help please.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nested-aggregation-with-and-always-return-0-match/315722?u=chattes